# Async in Asp.net MVC/WebAPI

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Using of Async and Await keyword is encourged in the recent conf with MS , If i use a Await keyword that can span a new thread in which the code will execute In which case what will happen to Asp.net Worker thread. Will it wait for the request to complete or will continue to serve other request .

Comment: see my tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`await` does not spawn a new thread. See my [`async`/`await` intro post](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) or the [`async`/`await` FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/10293335.aspx).

However, you *can* spawn a new task by explicitly calling `Task.Run`, if you want to.

When you call `await`, if the object you're awaiting is not already complete, then `await` will schedule the remainder of your `async` method to run later, and the current thread is returned to the thread pool. No threads are used by `async` or `await` while the asynchronous operation is in progress. When the asynchronous operation completes, the remainder of the `async` method runs on a thread pool thread (which may or may not be the same thread it started on). This is not normally a problem because in the common case (1), the `async` method resumes in the correct request context.

(1) The common case is that `await` is awaiting a `Task` or `Task<TResult>` directly.

Comment: K. But if the current thread returns to Thread pool , What will happen to thread affinity objects in the Thread. For example HttpContext.Current

Comment: `HttpContext.Current` and other ASP.NET instrinsics are part of the request context, so they flow to the new thread when the `async` method resumes.

Comment: But where do request context object are kept .It should need some Thread context for storing or it needs some Synchronous context to store it. Please correct me if i am wrong..

Comment: The request context is part of the `SynchronizationContext` in ASP.NET. By default, when you `await` a `Task`, the current `SynchronizationContext` is captured when the `async` method yields, and it's used to resume the remainder of the `async` method.